# How to make rages in named tables fixed in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In MS Excel, if "format as a table" is used the links do not look like `A1` or `B15` anymore but like `Table1[[#this row];[column1]]`

The problem is when copying these expressions to other cells they do not stay the same, but move. For "normal" links `$A1` or `$A$1`, but that does not seem to work for this named links.

Is there a way to achieve the same result that `$` causes to normal links for named links?

(I do not use English version of Excel, so some of the function names might be different.)

[Example Excel sheet](https://mega.co.nz/#!gR4jHbCK!BZ97-F4qOGX6Frh-nYAHzDRMcaJOfQTMqiRIcpole_g)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the Header you can use `INDIRECT()` to force it to use text to create the range you need.
Like `=INDIRECT("Table1[Coloumn1]")`

Indirect will also let you reference a cell that contains the text needed to to create the correct header. like `=INDIRECT("Table1["&A1&"]")` Where A1 contains "Column1"

Post your exact need with sample data and what you want to happen and I can help you further.